# Java -- Put NULL value into JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have an array of array, and each small array containt 3 Strings:

```
String errorParameters[][] = {
                { "MXL_001", "insertion error", "some string" },
                { "DLJ_040", "some other error", null },
                { "DLJ_042", "some other error", "some other string" }
        };
```

The last value sometimes can be null, like in the [1] array.
I pass this array to method that constructs some JSONObject and puts it into JSONArray.

```
public String myMethod(Object[][] errorParameters) {
        JSONArray errorMessages = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < errorParameters.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < errorParameters.length; j++) {
                if (errorParameters[i][j] == null) {
                    errorParameters[i][j] =  JSONObject.NULL;
                }
            }
            errorMessages.put(new JSONObject()
                    .put("attribute1", errorParameters[i][0])
                    .put("attribute2", errorParameters[i][1])
                    .put("attribute3", errorParameters[i][2]));
        }
        return errorMessages.toString();
    }
```

I expect the next JSON to be formed:

```
[
    {"attribute1":"MXL_001",
     "attribute2":"insertion error",
     "attribute3":"some string"
    },
    {"attribute1":"DLJ_040",
     "attribute2":"some other error",
     "attribute3":null
    },
    {"attribute1":"DLJ_042",
     "attribute2":"some other error",
     "attribute3":"some other string"
    },
]
```

But I got JSON without attribute which value is null:

```
[
    {"attribute1":"MXL_001",
     "attribute2":"insertion error",
     "attribute3":"some string"
    },
    {"attribute1":"DLJ_040",
     "attribute2":"some other error"
    },
    {"attribute1":"DLJ_042",
     "attribute2":"some other error",
     "attribute3":"some other string"
    },
]
```

Ane ideas how to put this null value into my JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just check the attribute value, so if its null simply do not put it on JSON and everything will be fine.

Comment: in my vase I need(!) to put it in JSON. So if value is null, I want to have "attribute1":null, and instead of it I don't have this attribute at all